# NullPointerException java circle project

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, geometry

I am doing a circle program where I have a point class with XY information. Here I am doing a circle class where I have couple methods to create the circle and the main method that has input data in it. However, i kept getting

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at hw_CircRect.circle.display(circle.java:26)
  at hw_CircRect.circle.main(circle.java:36)
```

Please help me take a look~ Greatly appreciated!
Here is my circle class code:

```
public class circle {
     private Point center;
     private double radius;
     private double area;

     public circle (Point center, double radius)
     {        
          center = new Point (center);
          area = radius * radius * 3.14;
     }

     public void display()
     {
          System.out.println("Circle Information:");
          center.print();
          System.out.println("Radius: "+radius);
          System.out.println("Area: "+area);       
     }

     public static void main (String[] args)
     {
          Point center = new Point(10,10);
          double radius = 4;
          circle c1 = new circle (center, radius);
          c1.display();        
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor is modifying its parameter instead of the class field. Use `this` to specify the latter:

```
this.center = new Point (center);
```

Alternatively, you can prevent shadowing by using a different name for the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the parameter `center` instead of your variable, so `c1.center` remains null, and when you try to access the variable you get `NullPointerException`. To fix use the keyword `this`:

```
public circle (Point center, double radius)
     {        
          this.center = new Point (center);
          area = radius * radius * 3.14;
     }
```